# Tensorflow and Cuda not compatible

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nvidia

I'm trying to run a GitHub code, using TensorFlow 1.x.
I'm using colab for this. I'm encountering this kind of problem which I can't find a solution to.
I'm using Tensorflow 1.15, my Cuda version installed is 10.1 and the Nvidia drive version in colab is NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05 Driver Version: 418.67.
When I tried to run another code above , cuda seems to be functional.
I'm using the GPU mode on colab
Can someone help me, please?
Thanks.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe the notebook session didn't connect the gpu, try restarting the session and wait for notebook to allocate the required resources.

Comment: I repeated this over 10 times, it didn't work, can you please tag someone who knows the issue , I'm stack here for over 10 days..

Answer (score 0):

Please share the link of Colab as I think you are not configuring the colab to use the GPUs. You can also follow the steps as,

1. Go to Colab
2. In the **edit** option at upper left corner
3. In the **Hardware accelerator** dropdown menu, select GPU.

Comment: I wasn't doing that, but the moment that I did it, that doesn't work either. Here is the colab link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XTgHAI0049b4At6ZNLrGNJnG-DZHLzmj?usp=sharing . and here is the github repo. that I'm referring to https://github.com/tau-yihouxiang/WS_DAN

Comment: 1. instaed of using !python to run the files, use %run [filename] to run the file.
2. use `%tensorflow_version 1.x` at the very first cell for using tensorflow 1.x, Dont install it again
3. no need to install all the cuda drivers. they are installed at the backend.
 just from Runtime do factory reset Runtime and, select GPU from hardware accelerator.